C++ Loop Iteration and Undefined Reference
Please note that this is a .cpp file that is being worked on as part of a larger program. To my knowledge, all other files work correctly. This is being done in Visual Studio Code.
Code:
#include "text-menu-app.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

TextMenuApp::TextMenuApp() {}

void TextMenuApp::run() {
    bool fileLoaded = false;
    string filename;
    bool errorMessageDisplayed = false; // Flag to track whether the error message has been displayed

    do {
        if (!errorMessageDisplayed) {
            cout << "Input the file name to load initial data from: ";
        }
        cin >> filename;
        if (patients.load(filename)) {
            fileLoaded = true;
            if (!errorMessageDisplayed) {
                cout << "File loaded!" << endl;
            }
            errorMessageDisplayed = false; // Reset error flag
        } else {
            cout << "File cannot be opened! Input again!" << endl;
            errorMessageDisplayed = true;
        }
    } while (!fileLoaded);

    int choice;
    do {
        cout << "1. Print all patients" << endl;
        cout << "2. Update patient information" << endl;
        cout << "3. Save to file" << endl;
        cout << "4. Exit" << endl;
        cout << "Please choose an option (1-4): ";
        cin >> choice;

        switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                patients.print();
                break;
            case 2: {
                int index;
                string name, gender;
                int age;
                cout << "Enter the index of the patient to update: ";
                cin >> index;
                if (index >= 0 && index < patients.getCount()) {
                    cout << "Enter patient name: ";
                    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                    getline(cin, name);
                    cout << "Enter patient age: ";
                    cin >> age;
                    cout << "Enter patient gender (Male/Female): ";
                    cin >> gender;
                    patients.updatePatient(index, name, age, gender);
                } else {
                    cout << "Invalid index!" << endl;
                }
                break;
            }
            case 3: {
                string filename;
                cout << "Input the file name to save the data to: ";
                cin >> filename;
                patients.save(filename);
                break;
            }
            case 4:
                cout << "Thank you for using the app!" << endl;
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Invalid option!" << endl;
        }
    } while (choice != 4);
}

Issue: I have tried several variations of the loop with no success in getting the correct output. I need it to output (see below) exactly once before going into the other part of the program. While attempting to fix this, somehow I have now made an "undefined reference to `TextMenuApp::run()'".. that I don't know how to fix. I think the issue is within the first loop.
Needed Output:
Input the file name to load initial data from: not-exist.txt
File cannot be opened! Input again!
Input the file name to load initial data from: patients.txt
File loaded!
Current Output:
Input the file name to load initial data from: non-exist.txt
File cannot be opened!
File cannot be opened! Input again!
Past Output:
Input the file name to load initial data from: no-exist.txt
File cannot be opened!
File cannot be opened! Input again!
Input the file name to load initial data from: patients.txt
File loaded!
File loaded!

The undefined reference you're experiencing isn't a compile-time error; it's a link-time error see here. Therefore, regardless of whether your logic in your loops is correct or not, it wouldn't cause that specific error.

You need to clarify. Does your code build and produces some output ? Or does it fail to build with a "undefined reference to `TextMenuApp::run()'" error? It cannot be both

Have you tried cleaning the build and building it again?
